# Angular - Conditional name depending on variable value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, conditional-statements

I have two global variables in my Typescript file:

```
private myVar1 = 10;
private myVar2 = 150;
```

I have a custom element which in the html can take `[name]` attribute. E.g. this is how a conditional name on my element would look like:

```
<custom-element [name]="myVar1 === 10 ? 'tempName' : 'someOtherTempName'"></custom-element>
```

In the case above the name will be **tempName** since myVar1 is 10. So far so good.

And now my question: how can I reference to `myVar1` or `myVar2` when the number (1 or 2) comes from another variable?

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
<custom-element [name]="('myVar'+index) === 10 ? 'tempName' : 'someOtherTempName'"></custom-element>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use a function with the array notation.

```js
getVar(index: number) {
  return this['myVar' + index];
}
```

```html
<custom-element [name]="getVar(index) === 10 ? 'tempName' : 'someOtherTempName'"></custom-element>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y29pcd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by collecting both elements into an array (or a dictionary, or any collection) and retrieving them using `index`

For instance add this dictionary

```
let vars = {1:var1, 2:var2}
```

and use it with

```
<custom-element [name]="vars[index] === 10 ? 'tempName' : 'someOtherTempName'"></custom-element>
```

Comment: There is "such thing" in JS.

Comment: What he's asking isn't "for a processor to generate the variable retrieval based on index". You have shifted the request to cope with your own definition of what he asked. There is a way to get dynamic variables names, this is the "such thing" I was talking about. Not your assumption. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: No there is no processor that's designed to generate variable access . If you're referring to your suggested solution - that's not reprocessing. This is done in runtime. Not saying yours is not a good solution (it's actually better than mine), it's just irrelevant to that point at hand.

Comment: Again, "such thing" refers to the OPs request, not your redefined assumption.

Comment: @trichetriche, You're right. I shifted the OP's question.